# Forcibly reduce usable CPU

Tags: cpu, overheating, fan, frequency

I'm looking for some sort of method to reduce the heat produced by my laptop. I was wondering if there is a method to throttle the CPU usage in Linux.

I have a laptop whose fan seems to be going a bit bad (I've dusted it, but still not good). I cannot replace it because the fan isn't produced anymore. I run simulations on this, so the CPU frequently goes to 100% usage but in general usage doesn't go above 20%. While running simulations the temp goes upto ~ 80-90 deg Celsius (Normally it is ~50).

Is there some method for me to force it to take up at maximum 50% of my CPU ?

PS :
I don't mind my simulations being a bit slow - but I don't want it to burn out the fan.
I already have a laptop cooling pad.
Also, I'm not sure about underclocking - I have not been able to find a method of doing it for my Core 2 Duo T2500.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. First, enable the power saving tools:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower. Then
you can set the upper limit the CPU should run at with: `sudo
cpufreq-set -u <freq>`, where `<freq>` would be of the format
"1.6Ghz".

Answer (score 0):

Thermald may help here.  It will actively monitor the thermal zones on your computer and try to use various cooling methods (e.g. CPU frequency scaling, throttling, etc) to stop your machine overheating.  To install, use:

```
sudo apt-get install thermald
```